# Get all array_agg() values with one matched value Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to get all array_agg() values with one matched value.

Like if in `robotsession."Session_OS"` there are multiple values ['Android', 'IOS', 'Windows']

In my current query it's giving ['Android'] only. But I want all.

My query is:

```
SELECT robotAds."Ad_ID",
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT quote_literal(robotSession."Session_OS"))
    as Session_OS
    FROM robot__ads robotAds LEFT JOIN
    robot__session__scraper__data robotScraper ON
    robotScraper."adIDAdID" = robotAds."Ad_ID" LEFT JOIN
    robot__session_data robotSession ON robotSession."id" = robotScraper."sessionIDId" WHERE
    robotScraper."sessionIDId" IS NOT NULL
    AND robotsession."Session_OS" IN ('Android')
    GROUP BY robotAds."Ad_ID"
```

In the result of this query is "Session_OS" gives only 'Android' value.

And sample data of this query is like:

```
  id   | Session_OS
-------|-------------
 641   | {'Android'}
 642   | {'Android'}
 643   | {'Android'}
```

But I want all the values that are IN Session_Os Agregation if it matched any of one. like here in my query it is matching with 'Android':

```
  id   | Session_OS
-------|-------------
 641   | {'Android, 'IOS'}
 642   | {'Android, 'Windows'}
 643   | {'Android', 'IOS', 'Windows'}
```

How I can achieve this ??

UPDATE:

Full data, without this condition in query `AND robotsession."Session_OS" IN ('Android')`

```
  id   | Session_OS
-------|-------------
 641   | {'Android, 'IOS'}
 642   | {'Android, 'Windows'}
 643   | {'Android', 'IOS', 'Windows'}
 644   | {'IOS', 'Windows'}
 645   | {'IOS'}
```

But after adding that condition `AND robotsession."Session_OS" IN ('Android')` in query result is

```
   id  | Session_OS
-------|-------------
 641   | {'Android'}
 642   | {'Android'}
 643   | {'Android'}
```

But I want this. How I can do that?

```
  id   | Session_OS
-------|-------------
 641   | {'Android, 'IOS'}
 642   | {'Android, 'Windows'}
 643   | {'Android', 'IOS', 'Windows'}
```

Comment: a) Please minimize your example code to the absolut necessary parts which are relevant to describe your problem. I.e. I guess, it's not necessary to show us 3 or 4 joins. b) Please add some sample data and the expected output, so that we could reproduce your problem

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick reply. I have updated my question. Kindly check again.

Comment: what is quote_literal(). Please show the data before grouping

Comment: quote_literal() Is nothing. You can ignore it. It is just add quote ('') to each value.

Comment: Kindly check updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=812f10e7eac65283bd17a350bebf623a)

```
SELECT
    id,
    ARRAY_AGG(session_os)
FROM
    t
GROUP BY id
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(session_os) && ARRAY['Android']
```

Your problem is that you FIRST filter the records with `session_os = Android`. And afterwards you are aggregate these.

You have to aggregate first and then have a look into the array aggregate if Android is an element. This can be done using the `HAVING` clause and the `&&` operator which returns true if two arrays contain the same element(s).

Comment: Hi, Thanks This is working. There is one more issue.
What if there is a null value in ARRAY_AGG(session_os) ?. It's throwing an error.
ERROR:  array must not contain nulls
SQL state: 22004

Comment: Hi, Thank This is working. There is one more issue.
    What if there is a null value in ARRAY_AGG(session_os) ?. It's throwing an error.
    ERROR:  array must not contain nulls
    SQL state: 22004

Comment: You can easily add a "WHERE session_os IS NOT NULL" filter before grouping: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f1a74e96da59a69181aef2d1920feab3

Comment: Why it's not allowing me to get NULL values as well ? If I am using "WHERE session_os IS NULL" and HAVING ARRAY_AGG(session_os) && ARRAY['Android']. It againg throwing same error. I can't do this. I can't get NULL values ?

Comment: See this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=09d427a849c5ff944c345b53554c7b48 . My case is like this... in this case how I can get null values as well.

Comment: I have created a new issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65308754/error-array-must-not-contain-nulls-postgresql