# ERROR: array must not contain nulls PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

My Query is

```
SELECT
    id,
    ARRAY_AGG(session_os)::integer[]
FROM
    t
GROUP BY id
HAVING ARRAY_AGG(session_os)::integer[] && ARRAY[1,NULL]
```

It's giving `ERROR:  array must not contain nulls`

Actually I want to get rows like

```
  id   | Session_OS
-------|-------------
 641   | {1, 2}
 642   | {NULL, 2}
 643   | {NULL}
```

Kindly check the sample data here

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7793fa763a360bf7334787e4249d6107

Comment: I only get this error when the extension intarray is installed (which dbfiddle apparently has installed by default, which is a bit strange to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` operator does not support `NULL` values. So, you need another approach. For example you could join the data to the table first. This gives you the `id`s which are linked to your required data. At the second step you are able to arregate all values using these `id`s.

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cb781639222a359a6dccb597a10b7628)

```
SELECT
    id,
    ARRAY_AGG(session_os)                        -- 4                         
FROM t
WHERE id IN (                                    -- 3
    SELECT 
        id
    FROM
        t
    JOIN (
        SELECT unnest(ARRAY[1, null]) as a       -- 1
    )s ON s.a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM t.session_os  -- 2
)
GROUP BY id
```

1. Create a table or query result which contains your relevant data, incl. the `NULL` value.
2. You can join the data, incl. the `NULL` value, using the operator `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`, which considers the `NULL`.
3. Now you have fetched the relevant `id` values which can be used in the `WHERE` filter
4. Finally your can do your aggregation

Comment: Thanks. Can you check when I am passing only null in array it's throwing an error.https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f464ac1ea22be735f94a351f45077dc1

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a1496395fd413481c797d4b93feee251 If your array contains only a NULL value, it is not clear which type the array is. so you have to cast it manually. In that case you have int values, which requires an int array

Comment: Thank. Working fine everything.

Answer (score 0):

The extension [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) installs its own `&&` operator for int[], and this doesn't allow NULLs and it takes precedence over the built-in `&&` operator.

If you are not using intarray, you can just uninstall it (except for in dbfiddle, where you can't).  If you are using it occasionally, I think it is best to install it in its own schema which is not in your search path.  Then you need to schema qualify its operators when you do need them.

Alternatively, you can leave intarray in place and schema qualify the normal built-in operators when you need those ones specifically, as shown [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1172c03f9517c3cb1eef9548f4ae9c5d).